# Free transaction on a private ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, contract-deployment, private-blockchain

I have developed a Dapp powered by Ethereum with truffle. And I want to deploy it on a private blockchain. But I have one question to ask before that.

My question is: can I make in sort that my Dapp don't request money (ETH) from users to use its functionalities (include reading and writing data) ?

I thank in advance anybody that will take the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the addresses an arbitrarily large amount of ETH when you start the network, and then have a way to mint ETH on demand. As it's a private network, that ether doesn't have any real value.